# Trigger if certain data matches - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `load_data and logs`.

I have written a trigger on the `load_data` table (mysql).The trigger inserts the data into the logs table on Updates.

I would like to insert the data in the "load_data" table If the following condition is met

If `diIndex=3 && diMode=0 && diStatus=1` then only execute insert statement.

I tried this but throws an error

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT 1 FROM box_data WHERE diIndex=3 
                      AND diMode=0 AND diStatus=1) = 0 THEN
         INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
         values("83","Plant","1","Trigger")
    END IF;
END//
```

DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

the following worked

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT 1 FROM load_data WHERE diIndex=3 and diMode=0 and diStatus=1)) THEN

       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
       VALUES("83","Plant","1","Trigger");

END IF;
```